# B Flat on Flute Is Too Flat

Tags: flute

B flat is too flat on my flute. The adjacent notes are fine. The adjacent notes go flat when I turn the flute towards me. It's easier to sharpen the octave. Pulling it out flattens it more and when it's pushed in all the way, the Bb is correct, but the other notes are too sharp. I tried twisting the screws and changing my embouchure, but I have to concentrate really hard on my embouchure to get it sharper. Is this normal?

Comment: Which B flat are you talking about?

Comment: You should post the brand and model, on the off chance that it's got known intonation problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about flute so I apologize if my information is correct, but I know when playing wind instruments it is good to keep a wide, open, and relaxed throat.

Push in your flute a little bit so that the Bb is better. Then, when you go to play the Bb, put your throat in the position as if you were making an "EE" sound; this will make the note sharper. Then, for your other notes, make that wide and open throat by "UH" or "OH" or whatever works.

This could also be a problem with leaks. Have you tried getting your instrument checked out at a shop?

Comment: I inherited my flute, so it's quite old, so it might be that there are leaks. Thanks!

Comment: Tho' if the note is flat, more likely that there's a key which isn't *open* properly, thus forcing the air column to be a bit longer than desired.  Same answer: take it to a repair shop.